# Change the mac address on an HC-05

Tags: bluetooth, hardware, hc-05

So I tried to save a little money and bought (5) HC-05 bluetooth modules off of our good buddy eBay.

When the modules arrived, as I was testing and setting up for my project (2 nano's connected via an HC-05 each to a Galaxy S4), I noticed all 5 modules shipped with the same MAC address.

I have been looking everywhere I can think of to modify the MAC address of the modules, but have had no luck.  Well, that isn't 100% accurate.  I found bdaddr on linux, but I do not have a linux machine.  Just Windows for me right now.

So, my issue is trying to find a way to set the HC-05 modules with different MAC addresses so I can have (2) connect at the same time to my S4.  I have been able to change the name of the units via the AT commands, just not the MAC address.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: i do not have any experience with the HC-05 module, but it looks like `AT+BIND=<Param>` sets the MAC ..... page 8 of this https://exploreembedded.com/wiki/images/a/a5/HC_05_Core_Datasheet.pdf

Comment: Any luck with this topic I have a similar problem on my HC-06 I have seen a set of instructions to update the firmware of the HC-05 and HC-06 on line and wonder if the MAC address can be changed during this process.